# How to make the MacBook always sleep / hibernate instead of shut down when power is too low?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Sometimes I left the MacBook there and forgot the plug the power in, and it would wake up from a sleep (or hibernation) when I plug the power in and wait a couple of minutes and press the power button again.

But sometimes it did wake up, but Google Chrome would mention it wasn't shut down properly, and the Terminal Bash seemed to have just started fresh too. So in this case it looked like it shut down instead of going into hibernation.

There is enough hard drive space to save all the data in RAM. For example, the hard drive might have 50GB of free space, and definitely was enough to save the 16GB of RAM of the MacBook for the later restore.

What might have caused it to shut down instead of hibernation? Is there a way to make it more certain to go into hibernation instead of shutting down?

Comment: The drained battery might cause this kind of a thing. It depends how many hours you left the "hibernated" mac unplugged. Also if you have 2015 or prior macbook with replaced NVME storage, this might also be the cause of this, since 3rd party NVME ssd's use more juice than apple ones. Better mention the device you are using in the question.

Comment: I thought when the MacBook goes into hibernation, then it won't drain the battery any more. It can be waken up 2 days later or 30 days later and it still would resume from the previous state, because everything was written to the hard drive and restored back to RAM.  So for example, when the computer shows you there is 1% or 2% battery left, internally it really has a little bit more, such as 3% (so it reported 1% or 2% less to do the hibernation), and then it saves all RAM to the hard drive, and just shut down the computer. When it is waken up, then it restores everything

Comment: The age of your MacBook Pro may be a factor. If the battery is old, managing very low levels may be unreliable.

Comment: @benwiggy it just happened to my MacBook Air M1... so it is brand new... at first I was wondering if some app cannot close (such as Terminal running something), but hibernating shouldn't require something to close or quit...